# How to make a SQL "IF-THEN-ELSE" statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I've seen other questions about SQL If-then-else stuff, but I'm not seeing how to relate it to what I'm trying to do. I've been using SQL for about a year now but only basic stuff and never this.

If I have a SQL table that looks like this

```
|  Name | Version | Category | Value | Number |
|:-----:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   123 |      1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   456 |      1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Final    |   789 |      1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   312 |      1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   645 |      1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Final    |   978 |      1 |
| File3 | 1.0     | Time     |   741 |      1 |
| File3 | 1.0     | Size     |   852 |      1 |
| File3 | 1.0     | Final    |   963 |      1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   369 |      2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   258 |      2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Final    |   147 |      2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   741 |      2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   734 |      2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Final    |   942 |      2 |
| File3 | 1.1     | Time     |   997 |      2 |
| File3 | 1.1     | Size     |   997 |      2 |
| File3 | 1.1     | Final    |   985 |      2 |
```

How can I write a SQL IF, ELSE statement that creates a new column called "Replication" that follows this rule:

```
A = B + 1 when x = 1
else 
A = B

where A = the number we will use for the next Number
B = Max(Number)
x = Replication count (this is the number of times that a loop is executed. x=i)
```

The results table will look like this:

```
|  Name | Version | Category | Value | Number | Replication |
|:-----:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|:-----------:|
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   123 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   456 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Final    |   789 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   312 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   645 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Final    |   978 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   369 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   258 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Final    |   147 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   741 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   734 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Final    |   942 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   997 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   997 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Final    |   985 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   438 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   735 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Final    |   768 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   786 |      2 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   486 |      2 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Final    |   135 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   379 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   943 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Final    |   735 |      2 |           2 |
```

**EDIT:** Based on the answer by Sean Lange, this is my 2nd attempt at a solution:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX)(Number) + CASE WHEN Replication = 1 then 1 else 0, 1) FROM Table
```

*The `COALESCE` is in there for when there is no value yet in the Number column.*

Comment: What version of SQL Serve are you using ?

Comment: NO your edits are all wrong. That is not how a case expression works. You can make it work like that but you would need to use subqueries. In this example why not use something like select coalesce(MAX(Number) + case when Replication = 1 then 1 else 0 end, 1) from Table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IF/Else construct is used to control flow of statements in t-sql. You want a case expression, which is used to conditionally return values in a column.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Yours would be something like:

```
case when x = 1 then A else B end as A
```

Comment: Couple of Questions: 1. does case work in the batch function `sqlcmd`? If not, then I'll just make a query file and execute it in the script.  2. (more importantly) I'll make an edit to my question, could you verify that it is correct syntax?

Comment: It is part of a query, it is NOT a stand alone mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

As SeanLange pointed out in this case it would be better to use an `CASE/WHEN` but  to illustrate how to use `If\ELSE` the way to do it in sql is like this:

```
 if x = 1
 BEGIN
 ---Do something
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 --Do something else
 END
```

I would say the best way to  know the difference and when to use which is if you are writing a query and want a different field to appear based on a certain condition, use `case/when`. If a certain condition will cause a series of steps to happen then use `if/else`